# Iterate Columns

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to setup a google store locator, I have the store locator working but I want to have which products are at the given store (There are only 7 products). I have a markers table which lists all the stores and address, I was thinking the best way would be to have a sub table that has a different column for each product and a 1 or 0 if the product is there or not.
My question is what is the best way to Iterate through the product table using php and see if the products are there and display some text if it is…
Is this the best way to do this does anyone have a better solution

Thanks

Craig

**tables:**

**markers**

```
id
name
address
```

**markers_products**

id    
marker_id
    product1 - int 1 if has product 0 or null if not
    product2
    product3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me if I've misunderstood your question but there seems to be a more fundamental issue to address first and that's your DB design.

I would have a table for markers, one for products and your link table that sits between called markers_products. Then simply add a record in your link table if a marker has a product.

Link Table

```
id
marker_id
product_id
etc
etc
```

This should then help you with your iteration issue.